# Improving Vara HF speeds

Tags: digital-modes, winlink

I'm using Winlink with a laptop hooked up to an IC-7300.
The registered version of Vara theoretically supports speeds up to 8,500 bps, but I'm seeing speeds more like 700 bp**m**. Is there anything I can try to improve the transfer rate, or is this just typical of real world performance?

- I've adjusted ALC to 1/3 scale
- SWR is 1.1
- Increasing TX power doesn't seem to help
- I tried increasing serial port baud rate from 9600 to 115200 and it made no discernable difference